# remove borders in mapkit

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I'm using Mapkit for an ios application, and i want to remove Borders between countries.
I found a javascript code that allows to make it using natively the google maps api:

```
[
{
featureType: "administrative.country",
stylers: [
  { visibility: "off" }
]
}
]
```

To do it using mapkit, is there any solution please??
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, not really (except you set `maptype` to `MKMapTypeSatellite`).

Long answer:

There is no public API in MapKit to remove country borders. And I guess It is also impossible with with private API because the map is build from static images (tiles).

In iOS 6 Apple has built their own map backend (without google maps) and MapKit has now dynamic rendering. There is a private framework (VectorKit) which is used under the hood to do the map rendering. So, maybe there is a chance using private API from VectorKit to hide the border lines in iOS 6.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i thought about MKMapTypeSatellite, but the client don't want it. To better understand the problem, the map of the country in which i'm working, is divided into two parts (it's political), but the client can't accept this. So apart to do that, do you have any idea?? Even if i could remove all borders i don't know if they can accept it!!! Really hate policy :( :( :(

Comment: My advice: don't use MKMapView at all and create your own map. Maybe draw a pdf layer inside a UIScrollView (I've done that in my own app).  Read this: http://www.veltema.jp/blog/2010/6/displaying-pdf-documents-on-ios-

Comment: But, i need the map of the whole country. They need to locate their sites across the country, with the streets ...etc

Comment: I admit it is a bigger effort to implement a map yourself, but its definitely possible. Search features can be implemented using google maps and places API or a local geo database.