# How to hide border using mapkit from iOS?

Tags: ios, mapkit

The question is in the title.

In my iOS application, I use MapKit and for some reasons I need to hide the borders between the countries, the frontiers.
How can I do that ? I tried to found a solution without any success for now.

I have already found that answer : [remove borders in mapkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756973/remove-borders-in-mapkit)
But it was in 2012, maybe there is a solution at now !

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: In fact, I want to remove the borders between the countries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove borders in mapkit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756973/remove-borders-in-mapkit)